# Jmeter .ASPXAUTH cookie handling

Tags: cookies, jmeter, session-cookies, .aspxauth

Action:
Login page enter a **username** and **password**, after that **.ASPXAUTH** cookie set and these are maintain all the rest of the http request

The above said cookie (**.ASPXAUTH**) not stored in cookie section. 
Please refer the screen shot

Response header set a **.ASPXAUTH** cookie

[image]

Once we pass the valid credentials request header (get method) maintain the same cookie throughout the session
[image]

Recorded the above login in jmeter while running the **.ASPXAUTH** cookie not set.

Let me know how can I handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cookie manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) for managing the cookie automatically. This will take care of your cookies and it works in most of the cases.You can also check the below URL on how to build a basic web test plan.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Uncomment the next line in *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.control" level="debug" />
   ```

   This way you will have way more information regarding what's going on with the HTTP Cookie Manager under the hood
2. Play with "Cookie Policy" dropdown values, i.e. try `netscape` which is less restrictive than `standard` which is "too"-[RFC 2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt)-compliant
3. Try adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   CookieManager.check.cookies=false
   ```

   It will suppress JMeter's cookies validation logic.

More information just in case: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)